# When is it better to use a vector than an array and vice versa in java?

Tags: java

When is it better to use a vector than an array and vice versa in java? and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use a List over an Array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589813/when-to-use-a-list-over-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Vector`: never, unless an API requires it, because it's a class, not an interface.

`List`: this should be your default array-like collection. It's an interface so anything can be a `List` if it needs to. (and there are lots of `List` implementations out there e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `ImmutableList`, for various feature sets)

`Vector` is threadsafe, but so is the `Collections.synchronizedList()` wrapper.

array: rarely, if required by an API. The one other major advantage of arrays is when you need a fixed-length array of primitives, the memory space required is fairly compact, as compared to a `List<Integer>` where the integers need to be boxed into `Integer` objects.

Answer (score 2):

A `Vector` (or `List`) when you don't know before hand how many elements are going to be inserted.

An `array` when you absolutely know what's the maximum number of elements on that vector's whole life.

Since there are no high performance penalties when using `List` or `Vector` (any collection for that matter), I would always chose to use them. Their flexibility is too important to not be considered.

Nowadays I only use `arrays` when I absolutely need to. Example: when using an API that requires them.

Answer (score 0):

First off ArrayList is a faster implementation than Vector (but not thread safe though).

Arrays are handy when you know the length beforehand and will not change much (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a method, use `List`.

Do not use `Vector`, it's an early part of the JDK and was retrofitted to work with `Collections`.

If there's a very performance-sensitive algorithm, a private array member can be helpful. If there's a need to return its contents or pass them to a method, it's generally best to construct an object around it, perhaps as simple as `Arrays.asList(thePrivateArray)`. For a thread-safe list: `Collections.synchronizedList(Arrays.asList(thePrivateArray))`. In order to prevent modification of the array contents, I typically use `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(thePrivateArray))`.