# How can I create array in Java?

Tags: java

I need something that in PHP would look (2D array):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => foo
        [desc] => some foo
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => bar
        [desc] => some bar
    )

)
```

All the java examples say that I should create "Integer [][] data;" or "String [][] data;" but here I have Int (index) and String... how to mix it?
How to populate it ...datas[i]["name"] = "aa" ?? 
How to read it in another Loop like:

```
for(int i=start;i<start;i++)
{
   value = data[i]["name"]...???
}
```

Comment: Java arrays use only `int`s as indexes. If you want words you are looking for `Map`

Answer (score 0):

As Pshemo say, java use only int as index for array.

You have plenty of solutions to achieve your objective. I will just present tree of them, both use an object container. Java is object programming, use them.

```
// Class declaration
public class SimpleContainer {

    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    public SimpleContainer(final String name, final String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }}
```

---

1, Use an array of object (not recommended):

```
 SimpleContainer[] simpleContainers = new SimpleContainer[3];
 simpleContainers[0] = new SimpleContainer("name 1", "description 1");
 simpleContainers[1] = new SimpleContainer("name 2", "description 2");
 simpleContainers[2] = new SimpleContainer("name 3", "description 3");

 for (int i = 0; i < simpleContainers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("I am [%s] and my description is [%s]",
         simpleContainers[i].getName(),
         simpleContainers[i].getDescription()));
}
```

---

2. Use a list instead of your array

In Java a rule of thumb is to use array only for primitive type (like int, bytes, ...). And use list for others types. For more details, read:

1. [When to use a List over an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589813/when-to-use-a-list-over-an-array-in-java)
2. [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster)

Some simple example of list usage (same object) :

```
List<SimpleContainer> myList = new ArrayList<SimpleContainer>();
myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 1", "description 1"));
myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 2", "description 2"));
myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 3", "description 3"));

// Use iterator (support remove object for most list implementations).
        Iterator<SimpleContainer> it = myList.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {
     SimpleContainer simpleContainer = it.next();
     System.out.println(String.format("I am [%s] and my description is [%s]",
     simpleContainer.getName(),
     simpleContainer.getDescription()));
}

// Or simple loop.
for (SimpleContainer simpleContainer : myList) {
     System.out.println(String.format("I am [%s] and my description is [%s]",
     simpleContainer.getName(),
     simpleContainer.getDescription()));
}
```

Understand the collections in Java is very important, just check a tutorial like :
[Simple tutorial about collections](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/index.html)

---

3. Use a hashmap who represent an association between two objects. Hashmap is the preferred solution if the main action you want is to find any association.

   ```
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("name 1", "description 1");
    myMap.put("name 2", "description 2");
    myMap.put("name 3", "description 3");

    String description = myMap.get("name 1");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it =    myMap.entrySet().iterator();

     while (it.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
   ```

---

4. Maybe you want to use a double index with int and string, in this case you can use one example of this page :
   [Double key indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822322/how-to-implement-a-map-with-multiple-keys)

---

5. Finally you can use predicate (java 8 or guava librarie). There is an example of usage of guava predicate.

   ```
   public void ExamplePredicate() {
   List<SimpleContainer> myList = new ArrayList<SimpleContainer>();
   myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 1", "description 1"));
   myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 2", "description 2"));
   myList.add(new SimpleContainer("name 3", "description 3"));

   // Get one index :
   System.out.println(myList.get(1).getDescription());

   // Try to find an entry with name.
   Optional<SimpleContainer> optContainer = Iterables.tryFind(myList, new NameContainerPredicate("name 1"));
   if (optContainer.isPresent()) {
       System.out.println(optContainer.get().getDescription());
   }

   // Try to find an entry with name between two index.
   Optional<SimpleContainer> optContainer2 = Iterables.tryFind(myList.subList(1, 2), new NameContainerPredicate("name 1"));
   if (optContainer2.isPresent()) {
       System.out.println(optContainer2.get().getDescription());
   } else {
       System.out.println("No entry found");
   }

   // Get all entry with given name.
   List<SimpleContainer> containersList = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(myList.subList(1, 2), new NameContainerPredicate("name 1")));
   for (SimpleContainer simpleContainer : containersList) {
       System.out.println(String.format("Name [%s]  description [%s]", simpleContainer.getName(), simpleContainer.getDescription()));
   }
   }

   private static class NameContainerPredicate implements Predicate<SimpleContainer> {

   private final String name;

   public NameContainerPredicate(final String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean apply(@Nullable final SimpleContainer input) {
       return input != null && equal(input.getName(), name);
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Or just use a hashmap, since it represents an "associative array" which is what PHP uses.

Comment: Thanks guys. If I read well your 1-2 solutions Manticore offer simple List nothing more. I need 2D array. HashMap is interesting but I cannot find example how to get concrete index from it; what I'm doing in PHP with array[index][key]. For instance I want third index from Hashmap....

Comment: Have you an example of usage, because I think you want an array but you don't need one.