# Java - Multiple fields of same data type in an object

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, composition

I was practicing inheritance and composition after a lesson and decided to write a small program to try some things out, stumbled upon a problem, I'll show my code, it has 4 classes including the Main.java:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person1 = new Person("Person1", 170); //"Name", height
    Person person2 = new Person("Person2", 200); //"Name", height

    Bed bed1 = new Bed(160);

    Bedroom bedroom1 = new Bedroom(bed1, person1);

    bedroom1.sleep();
```

```
public class Bedroom {

private Bed theBed;
private Person thePerson;

//Constructors

public void sleep() {
    if(thePerson.getHeight() > 180) {
        System.out.println("You are too tall to sleep on this bed.");
    } else {
        theBed.sleepOnBed();
    }
}

//Getters
```

```
public class Bed {

private Person thePerson;
private int height;

//Constructor

public void sleepOnBed() {
        System.out.println("You sleep on the bed.");
}

//Getters
```

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private int height;

//Constructor

//Getters
```

What I want to do is to use both `person1` and `person2` in my `bedroom1` object in Main.java and then test the `sleep()` method on both of them but I just can't figure out a way to use it.

I tried things like:

```
public class Bedroom {

private Bed theBed;
private Person thePerson1;
private Person thePerson2;

public Bedroom(Bed theBed, Person thePerson1, Person thePerson2) {
    this.theBed = theBed;
    this.thePerson1 = thePerson1;
    this.thePerson2 = thePerson2;
} 


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person person1 = new Person("Person1", 170);
    Person person2 = new Person("Person2", 200);

    Bed bed1 = new Bed(160);

    Bedroom bedroom1 = new Bedroom(bed1, person1, person2);

    bedroom1.sleep();
```

But as you might understand, that lead to nothing. I'm just so tired and can't find any leads online, might be because I use the wrong keywords idk.

I want my program to take multiple objects of data type `Person` and see if their height matches the conditions to sleep in the bed, that's pretty much it.

Comment: You can define an `array of Person`, and pass that to `Bedroom` constructor. Then you can iterate over the array and check the condition you want. When you do that, you will need to set in the `Bed` object the person that validated the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace Person with a List of Person objects in the bedroom class and then loop over the array in the sleep method.

```
public Bedroom(Bed bed1, List<Person> aListOfPersons)
{
  this.persons = aListOfPersons;
}

public void sleep()
{
  for(Person aPerson : persons)
   {
      //check for each aPerson if he fits in the bed
   }
 }
```

Welcome to Stackoverflow and happy coding!

Comment: Unless you are using primitives, it's generally a good idea to use `List<Person>` instead of an array. That way you don't care what the implementation is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589813/when-to-use-a-list-over-an-array-in-java

Comment: Ah darn it! I haven't gotten to arrays or lists in my course yet! Thanks for the answer and the warm welcome.

Comment: @Nedotian If this has answered your question, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: @Novaterata Thanks for the info, I have changed the code accordingly.