# Enums implementing interface are rejected by verifier (java.lang.VerifyError)

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm using enums for units of different physical quantities, like `meter` and `miles` for the `DISTANCE`. To use them in a generic way there is an interface `Unit` which has the method `convert(double)`.

To load the preferred units, a singleton is used:

```
public class UnitPreferences {

    private static UnitPreferences sInstance;

    private HashMap<PhysicalQuantity, Unit> mUnits;

    /**
     * Returns the instance of the preferred units collection.
     *
     * @param context the context
     * @return Instance of the preferred units collection.
     */
    public static UnitPreferences from(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new UnitPreferences(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new set of preferred units by fetching them from the Shared Preferences.
     *
     * @param context the resources
     */
    private UnitPreferences(Context context) {
        // Load the preferred units from SharedPreferences and put them in the mUnits HashMap
    }

    /**
     * Returns all units of a specific physical quantity.
     *
     * @param physicalQuantity the physical quantity
     * @return All units available to this physical quantity.
     */
    private Unit[] getAllUnits(PhysicalQuantity physicalQuantity) {
        switch (physicalQuantity) {
            case DISTANCE:
                return DistanceUnit.values();

            // others...

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("No units defined for " + physicalQuantity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the preferred unit of a physical quantity.
     *
     * @param phQuantity the physical quantity
     * @return The preferred unit.
     */
    public Unit getPreferredUnit(PhysicalQuantity phQuantity) {
        return mUnits.get(phQuantity);
    }
}
```

The `PhysicalQuantity` enum:

```
public enum PhysicalQuantity {

    DISTANCE,
    // others...

}
```

The `Unit` interface:

```
public interface Unit {

    double convert(double value);

}
```

The `DistanceUnit` implementing the `Unit` interface:

```
public enum DistanceUnit implements Unit {

    KILOMETER(R.string.unit_km, "km"),
    MILES(R.string.unit_mi, "mi");

    public static final double KM_PER_MI = 1.609344d;

    private int label;
    private String id;

    DistanceUnit(int label, String id) {
        this.label = label;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public double convert(double meters) {
        double km = meters / 1000d;
        if (this == MILES) return km / KM_PER_MI;
        return km;
    }
}
```

#### The Problem:

The exception is thrown the first time I'm using the units:

```
Unit distanceUnit = UnitPreferences.from(context).getPreferredUnit(DISTANCE);
```

When I implemented it everything worked fine, now after it was merged into the master I'm getting a `VerifyError`

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.example.app.UnitPreferences: com.example.app.Unit[]
  com.example.app.UnitPreferences.getAllUnits(com.example.app.PhysicalQuantity) failed to verify:
  com.example.app.units.Unit[] com.example.app.UnitPreferences.getAllUnits(com.example.app.PhysicalQuantity):
  [0x28] returning 'Reference: java.lang.Enum[]', but expected from declaration 'Reference: com.example.app.Unit[]'
  (declaration of 'com.example.app.UnitPreferences' in /data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk:classes32.dex)
```

I've already cleaned and rebuild several times and turned off Instant Run. Can anyone give me a hint how to fix this error?

Comment: I believe that came from some other tools(covertural..?).

Comment: What kind of tools do you mean? I don't think there is anything which would cause this crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked into the stacktrace a little more and it says:

```
returning 'Reference: Enum[]', but expected from declaration 'Reference: Unit[]'
```

in `getAllUnits()`

Casting the returned enums of `getAllUnits()` to `Unit[]` manually fixed the issue although there is a hint:

```
Casting 'DistanceUnit.values()' to 'Unit[]' is redundant
```

[image: Casting Unit[] manually]

Answer (score 2):

This part seems key:

```
returning 'Reference: java.lang.Enum[]', but expected from declaration 'Reference: com.example.app.Unit[]
```

So you are returning an enum array when you should be returning a unit array. Change either the return type of the method, or simply pack the DistanceUnit values into a list to fix the problem.

I would recommend using `List<Unit>` as your return type instead of `Unit[]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589813/when-to-use-a-list-over-an-array-in-java) for reference. To do so, call `Arrays.asList(DistanceUnit.values())` when instantiating your list.

Comment: Good point but if I use `Arrays.asList(DistanceUnit.values())` and change the return type to `List<Unit>` I'm getting an error `Incompatible types: Required List<Unit> - Found List<DistanceUnit>`. So I have to cast it to `Unit[]` first and do `Arrays.asList((Unit[]) DistanceUnit.values())`. Then I rather use just the cast and keep `Unit[]` as return type.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Sorry I wasn't more thorough with checking such things in my answer; I don't have access to my personal Java environment while I'm at work.